# Is it safe to save the Firebase Server Key in the Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm making a notification submission process in android studio and I know it's not safe to leave the Firebase Cloud Messaging Server Key in the source code directly, so would it be safe if I put the key directly through the Realtime Database dashboard into a node and retrieve the key from the source code using valueSingleEventListener every time I send a notification?

Answer (score 0):

No. While loading the key dynamically is marginally more secure than storing the key in the application code itself, it's still no barrier for a malicious user. It's really quite simple: to securely send messages from one device to another device  with Firebase Cloud Messaging you'll need to run code in a trusted environment, such as your development machine, a server that you control, or Cloud Functions.

Also see:

- [Retrieve the FCM server key from the Firebase remote configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42542631/retrieve-the-fcm-server-key-from-the-firebase-remote-configuration/42544342#42544342)
- [Firebase server key and sender id exposed to public](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51647892/firebase-server-key-and-sender-id-exposed-to-public/51655392#51655392)
- [Is FCM on the web secure without an app server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41599970/is-fcm-on-the-web-secure-without-an-app-server/41600598#41600598)
- [Firebase messaging without server XMPP server - Proposal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41853694/firebase-messaging-without-server-xmpp-server-proposal/41853937#41853937)
- [Where should I store my FCM server key if not on client side for security? iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53183533/where-should-i-store-my-fcm-server-key-if-not-on-client-side-for-security-ios/53183626#53183626)

Comment: But in case it would not be safe if the misguided person could find out my Firebase account email and password, right? Because if I only have the Firebase account password, only I can see the data from the database

Comment: If someone gets your Google account credentials that you use to sign in to the Firebase console, then indeed they have access to all your data *including* the FCM server keys. The difference is that someone getting access to your Google account credentials is not a normal part of building an app, while sending the app to your users is a normal part of that.